# Discord.py - Cannot try/except 403: User does not accept DMs

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

I've been looking everywhere for this, but the try/except never worked for me and got me multiple errors. The code is to ban every member from server and send a DM that the server was deleted. It works, but the bot stops at a person with the error "Cannot send messages to this user" and I'd like to handle it, but always got errors like: `indent expected` or `expression expected`. The code I have without try/catch is:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def abandon(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if len(member.roles) < 2:
            await member.send(f"Hello {member.display_name},\n\n" + banreason + banreason2 + banreason3)
            await member.ban(reason="Executed due to deletion of the server. Invite links were sent in DMs.")
            await ctx.send(f"**{member.display_name}** was banned and invite links were sent. :white_check_mark:")
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name} and invite links were sent.")
    print("Banning complete!")
```

How can I import a correct try/catch bracket around `await member.send`?

EDIT: Added code with the exception handling:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def abandon(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if len(member.roles) < 2:
            try:
            print(f"Debug: Targeted user is {member.display_name}")
            except CommandInvokeError:
            ctx.send(f"{member.display_name}" + resolvedmerror)
            print(f"{member.display_name} was banned with 403 Forbidden exception (No DMs accepted by user)")
            pass
            await member.send(f"Hello {member.display_name},\n\n" + banreason + banreason2 + banreason3)
            await member.ban(reason="Executed due to deletion of the server. Invite links were sent in DMs.")
            await ctx.send(f"**{member.display_name}** was banned and invite links were sent. :white_check_mark:")
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name} and invite links were sent.")
    print("Banning complete!")
```

Comment: That's a syntax error. Post your error with the try except block.

Comment: added to main post.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the simple format problem by using space instead of tab. Haha python is oversensitive and I thought something is needed, but was only one press.